# iterate all sheets in c# with epplus and importing them in the combobox

Tags: c#, epplus

I want to place all sheet names of a specific excel in items of a combo box with c# using [epplus](/questions/tagged/epplus). Can you help me how to do that? thank you

Comment: [Please read the help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to post a more complete question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you want to read all the names of an Excel and place the names of the Excel Worksheets into a combobox, so the user can pick it up, am I right?

```
 var filePath = "C:\\temp\\excel.xlsx";
 var excel = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filePath));

 foreach (var worksheet in excel.Workbook.Worksheets)
 {
     this.comboBox1.Items.Add(worksheet.Name);
 }
```

If you replace the file path with your file path excel name and change the comboBox1 to be your combo box I think that this is what you want.

[image]